# SQL Server 2016 Management Studio - missing 'Edit top 200' options

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just install new version of SQL Server 2016 Management Studio 
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx).

I don't know why but there is no some typical options as 'Edit top 200 rows', 'Design table' or option for add new table. Does anyone some ideas why? I can do all of this via SQL scripts (its actually how I created table from Print-screen).

Maybe I am missing installation of some tools?

Thanks for help.

[image: Edit top 200 rows is missing]

**EDIT:**

Looks like same issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2883440

Comment: Do you have the permission?

Comment: this seems to be a bug. [Look here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4138fb17-b4bf-4586-bc4a-621e72ed11ff/edit-top-200-rows-missing-in-july-2016-smss?forum=sqltools)

Comment: @ydoow : what kind of permission? I am able to work with data through SQL commands.  It is why i think that it is not about permissions.

Comment: @lokusking : thank you for link. It seems like same problem. I will wait for MS reply.

Comment: This question is not about programming and should've been posted on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I see the option in SSMS 2016 version 13.0.15000.23.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bug is fixed - hotfix is issued yesterday:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/library/mt238290.aspx
```

direct download link:

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=822301
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Probably there is a bug in SSMS16

[SQL Server 2016 Express Management Studio cannot design a new or existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213508/sql-server-2016-express-management-studio-cannot-design-a-new-or-existing-table)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219360/2470789