# SQL Server 2016 Express Management Studio cannot design a new or existing table

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, sql-server-express, ssms-2016

In Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Express Management Studio (July 2016) cannot design a new or existing table.

Image 1: click on the tables node. Where is the menu option to add a new table?

[image: Where is the menu option to add a new table?]

Image 2: Click on existing table. Where is the menu option to edit an existing table?

[image: Where is the menu option to edit an existing table?]

Version: [SQL Server 2016 Management Studio (July 2016)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

[image: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express Info]

Thanks!

Comment: Does your login have the permission to create new tables ?

Comment: Permissions problem? Try running `CREATE TABLE Test (col1 INT)` and see what happens.

Comment: @DavidG: Result => Command(s) completed successfully.

Comment: Yes! @M.Ali... check the DavidG's comment.

Comment: Just to confirm, did you run that command in the same database where you want to create the table?

Comment: Yes @DavidG, however the problem occurs with any database!

Comment: What version of SQL Server is the database that you are trying to modify? SSMS for SQL Server 2016 will not maintain databases of 2008R2 or before  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195071/create-new-table-is-not-visible-on-ssms-2016-for-sql-server-2008/38213611#38213611

Comment: @Mike the same, SQL Server 2016 express edition

Comment: OK, I have deleted my answer since it wasn't relevant to you, but i will leave the comment to redirect those who may have that issue

Comment: @oneNiceFriend more details in this question!

Comment: What is the compatibility level of the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug:

[Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2883440)

[social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/346a5a23-1f60-4c6d-ab98-3805edba1016/where-is-design-table-in-ssms-2016-july-release?forum=sqltools)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released a hotfix for this issue already. You can download it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstall the July edition and re-install the [June edition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-sql-server-management-studio-june-2016-release/), things will be back to "normal" for you. You do lose the Azure support, however.