# Not seeing "Execute stored Procedure" in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016-express

Is anybody else having an issue when they right click on an SP, and not seeing the option to execute the SP? Only option that I have is to script as execute. I am running SQL Server 2016 express.

Comment: I have seen other posts with problems with the July build of SSMS 2016. They were reporting that "Create Table" was missing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213508/sql-server-2016-express-management-studio-cannot-design-a-new-or-existing-table/38219360#38219360

Comment: After install, can I roll back without hurting the DB

Comment: I suggest that you back up the database now. Full and transaction. Then check the Compatibility level. Change it back to your previous version of SQL server. Take another back up (to a new file!!).

Comment: They release a monthly update, so hopefully they will get it fixed on the next release. I guess I am just old school and miss the pop up box for param validations lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too long for comment!**

I suggest that you back up the database now. Full and transaction.

Then check the Compatibility level. Change it back to your previous version of SQL server. Take another back up (to a new file!!).

Now did you upgrade the whole of SQL server or just SSMS? You could just install another earlier version of SSMS and leave the existing server in place and running, test to see if the functionality is all still there with the new (older) SSMS and the old (Ok most recently installed SQL Server).

Microsoft are doing monthly releases of SSMS so it is changing fast - which can mean bugs, but the server should be more stable, so the problem could just be a SSMS issue and your database could be fine.

Comment: What confuses me is that I have 3 DB that I am logged into in the same SSMS 2016- DB1 is missing options, DB2 and DB3 have all of the options. I logged into DB1 with SSMS 2014 and had all of the options. Explain that please??? My DB1 Version is 12.SQL. I wonder if that has an effect on it

Comment: probably worth having a look on the DBA site of Stack Exchange, to see what comes up there. I have done some googling, a few issues with July release, but not much detail. I will stay with 2012 for a bit longer!!

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to download a revision quickly and didn't think about the beta. So I did some research and found that they know about and have validated the whole issue and are trying to release another update to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

New patch came out. It works wonderfully now. My issue was resolved. Thanks for the help...