# How to reenable missing Context Menus on SSMS July 2016

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2016

I installed latest SSMS (July 1, 2016 Edition) and for some reason some of my context menus are gone.
For ex:

- Edit Top 200 Rows
- Rebuild Index

It is only specific to certain SQL server. But, I found that my other machine with same SSMS edition still has the context menus on that particular SQL server.

How can I re-enable these context menus?

I tried reparing the installation, but it did not work out. My only last resort is uninstall and re-install which I have not done yet, but if you have better solution than this, please let me know.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213508/sql-server-2016-express-management-studio-cannot-design-a-new-or-existing-table/38219360#38219360

Comment: Looks like the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @msanz mentioned in the comment, this is a bug of SSMS July 2016 edition.
So the solution is either:

1. re-install the June version:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238488.aspx
2. Or wait until the July fixed edition comes out mid July. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2883440